# Hadle cartlyst strip plan error

Tags: laravel-5, stripe-payments

I am creating payment plan for strip using cartalyst strip API in my laravel application, it working correctly but when strip shows any error, it directly showing in the DOM. I want to store it in a variable and then redirect to the previous page. I have used `try...catch` method but it was not working for the create plan.

Below is my code

```
$stripe = Stripe::make(STRIPE_KEY);
try {
    $plan = $stripe->plans()->create([
              'id'                    => 'monthly',
              'name'                  => 'palan name'
              'amount'                => '22',
              'currency'              => 'USD',
              'interval'              => 'month',
              'interval_count'        => '6',
              'statement_descriptor'  => 'test description'
            ]);
}
catch (Stripe\Error\Base $e) { 
    echo($e->getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that library but I think the issue is that you are not catching the errors properly here as Cartalyst has those in their own namespace. You can see this in their [documentation](https://cartalyst.com/manual/stripe/2.0#exceptions) where they give some examples on how to catch errors:

```
try {
    $customer = $stripe->customers()->find('foobar');

    echo $customer['email'];
} catch (Cartalyst\Stripe\Exception\NotFoundException $e) {
    // Get the status code
    $code = $e->getCode();

    // Get the error message returned by Stripe
    $message = $e->getMessage();

    // Get the error type returned by Stripe
    $type = $e->getErrorType();
}
```

They don't mention how to catch the `Base` one though and I don't have access to the code to double check but I'd guess it's an oversight and you can simply catch `Cartalyst\Stripe\Exception\Base $e`

Comment: I will implement it, and let you know. Thanks